# JQuery radio button checked

Tags: jquery

I have a problem I can't solve with JQuery and radio buttons.
What I want to do is to check if a radio button is selected, if it is I change the style of its container.
I have the folowing :

```
if ($("input:radio").is(":checked")) {

    $(".panel").addClass("panel-active");
}
```

Now this checks if a radio button is checked and if it is so,the relevant class is added to its parent, but it adds the class to all parent, as expected.

I only want to add the class to the checked radio button's parent.

I tried this

```
$(this).parent().addClass("panel-active");
```

But this doesnt seem to do anything.

How can I get this working?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show more code and HTML? Like where is this condition placed? in a change event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make a loop of all radio buttons first, to check each one and append the class to its parent:

```
$("input:radio").each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("panel-active");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this has done it thanks. I actually needed to add it to its parents parent in the end as I hadn't realised its depth but doing this each loop worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try this :

```
$("input:radio:checked").parent().addClass("panel-active");
```

Or something like that ?

Answer (score 2):

see this fiddle. jsfiddle.net/7VXXN/

If you have more than one checkbox and first is checked than all the parent have the class "panel-active". use $.each instead.